# Generating vector of maps

Tags: clojure, data-generation

I need to generate vector of maps filled with random data, that look something like this:

```
  {
    :amount 9999
    :booking-date  "2015-12-21"
    :effective-date  "2015-12-21"
    :id  "01244f01-1933-4a8d-8b92-07796e3e62f0"
    :reconciled false
    :transaction_id  "000014543583"
  }
```

I was thinking to use either `clojure/data.generators` or 'clojure.test.check/generators`,
being new to clojure struggling with that. Can you trow me a code snippet. Thanks

Comment: Don't tell us that you're struggling. Show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see an example for test.check in some unit tests for the [Tupelo Library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/tst/tupelo/base64.clj#L55).

I would also recommend looking at all of the examples and links at the GH page for test.check:  https://github.com/clojure/test.check